# Problems to multicast a files in Apache Camel

Tags: java, file, apache-camel, sftp

guys.

I have to process 10 files in parallel using apache camel and send then via the FTP command. I've made some research and I heard about a "multicast()" command. But it apparently does not work because I'm receiving the files one by one in the server... :/

My file route:

```
 fromF("file://%s?antInclude=**/*.sync&recursive=true&noop=true", configurationManager.getDestinationFilesFolderPath())
        .routeId("FTP_Snapshot_Fetcher")
        .setHeader("OriginalFileName", simple("${file:name.noext}"))
        .multicast()
        .parallelProcessing()
            .to(ftpRoutesForSameGroup.split(separator))
            .toD("file://" + configurationManager.getDestinationFilesFolderPath() + "?fileName=${in.header.OriginalFileName}" + DAConfigurations.FILE_EXTENSION);
```

I've tried to use it with pipeline and to, but both options don't have any effect.

There are any possibility of the sftp component be the leak?

It looks like:

```
.toD("sftp://"
                + ftpEndpoint.getUser() + "@"
                + ftpEndpoint.getUrl()  + ":"
                + ftpEndpoint.getPort() + "/ftp/${in.header.pathToFile}"
                + "?password=" + ftpEndpoint.getPassword()
                + "&autoCreate=true&passiveMode=true&binary=true&tempFileName=${file:name.noext}"
                + DAConfigurations.FILE_EXTENSION_ON_SYNC
            )
```

This `ftpRoutesForSameGroup` is a string that contains all route list separated (e.g.: "direct:r1;direct:r2;direct:r3").

Does someone knows how to fix it to the correct way (send all files, or the maximum possible in parallel)?

Comment: Multicast will send the same message to one or more endpoints in parrallel it will not send all the messages in parrallel. You could use a seda route to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Camel documentation:

The Multicast allows to route the same message to a number of endpoints and process them in a different way.

So what happens is, the file content is given to the four routes and all of them process the same content and does the same thing.

For your requirement, try using SEDA component which forks out a new thread for further processing.

[SEDA COMPONENT](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/seda.html)